# ConversionNotSupportedException saving jpa entity with @IdClass primary key though service in Spring Boot

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, service, spring-data

I get a odd error when trying to save an JPA entity with an @IdClass primary key. Using test and saving entity directly to the repository works without involving transactions but when going through a Service it throws an Error.

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'xxx.yyy.model.entity.TournamentEntity_$$_jvstffa_0' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'tournament'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'xxx.yyy.model.entity.TournamentEntity_$$_jvstffa_0' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'tournament': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:453)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$IdentifierDerivingDirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:340)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:232)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.save(Unknown Source)
    at xxx.yyy.service.TournamentService.createParty(TournamentService.java:104)
```

My TournamentEntity class looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOURNAMENT")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TournamentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tournament", cascade = ALL)
    List<PartyEntity> parties;
}
```

My PartyEntity class that seems to be the problem looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTY")
@ToString(exclude = "tournament")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@IdClass(PartyId.class)
public class PartyEntity {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TOURNAMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private TournamentEntity tournament;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARTY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String partyId;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private PartyState state;
}
```

And the PartyId class which holds the primary key looks like this and this is where the mapping seems to fail:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PartyId implements Serializable {
    private String tournament;
    private String partyId;
}
```

In the TournamentService class the save throws the exception:

```
@Transactional
public PartyEntityDTO createParty(String tournamentId) {
    TournamentEntity tournament = tournamentRepository.getOne(tournamentId);
    PartyEntity party = tournamentPartyRepository.save(PartyEntity.builder().tournament(tournament).state(REGISTERED).partyId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build());
    return modelMapper.map(party, PartyEntityDTO.class);
}
```

However, using repository directly works perfectly fine. Running the following test adds Party to the database. Involving no surrounding Transaction annotation

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
//@Transactional
public class PartyDatabaseTest {

    @Autowired
    private TournamentPartyRepository partyRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TournamentRepository tournamentRepository;

        @Test
        public void testInsertEntry() {
            TournamentEntity loadedTournament = tournamentRepository.findAll().get(0);
            PartyEntity party = partyRepository
                    .save(PartyEntity
                            .builder()
                            .tournament(loadedTournament)
                            .partyId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                            .state(REGISTERED)
                            .build());
        }
}
```

Any suggestion to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated!